# Application crashes on changing Application Bar visibility

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a panorama application and I want to custumize an application bar, so it will be visible only for a single page.
I have created the Application bar in XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="AppBar_Opere" IsVisible="False" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Default" Opacity="0.95" >

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/feature.search.png" Text="cauta" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar1/favs.png" Text="favorite" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/AppBar2/feature.settings.png" Text="setari" />

        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Clasa a IX-a" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Clasa a X-ea" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Clasa a XI-ea" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Clasa a XII-ea" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>

    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Then, using SelectionChanged event, I writen this code:

```
private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(((Panorama)sender).SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                AppBar_Opere.IsVisible = true;
                break;
            default:
                AppBar_Opere.IsVisible = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Ok. When I navigate to the page where I want the ApplicationBar to be visible, the app crashes, with "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**"
On line:

```
AppBar_Opere.IsVisible = true;
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ApplicationBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is not a silverlight control, so you can't access it that way.
Correctly code is:

```
private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(((Panorama)sender).SelectedIndex)
    {
         case 1:
             ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
             break;
         default:
             ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
             break;
    }
}
```